# Me.Controls does not find all controls on the form

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have a form that takes a list of search terms, and creates a combo box for each result set. The boxes get created at runtime, they are all individually named, and are all directly on the form, none are in panels or any sub controls.

I want to remove the previous searchs combo boxes every time a new search is done. I made the following sub to remove all combo boxes

```
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If c.GetType Is GetType(ComboBox) Then 
            Me.Controls.Remove(c)
            c.Dispose()
        End If
    Next c
```

But for some mysterious reason, the Form doesn't see all the combo boxes the previous search created. If I create 3 boxes, it will see the first and third, but not the second. If I run the sub again, it will see the second one and catch it that time. So I need to run the sub twice to actually clear out all the comboboxes that were created. I checked the control collection and it seems to always be 1 short of the actual number of combo boxes that were created in the previous search

Any idea why it is always leaving a combo box behind and I need to clear them all again a second time to get rid of it?

Comment: The reason is not mysterious, you're using a `For Each` on a collection of Control, then disposing of items in the collection, which will modify the collection you're iterating over, so you'll dispose of half of the Controls. Use a backwards `For` loop, or create a List of those Controls and iterate over this new list. Or use a forward `For` loop and dispose at `(0)`. -- The Controls collection changes when you dispose of a Control, because disposing of a Control also removes it from the collection. BTW, you should have `For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)`

Comment: Note that to @Jimi 's comment, .NET will often fail with an error if you modify a collection while it is in the process of being enumerated.

Answer (score 2):

Further to what Jimi said in the comments, I would recommend that you use this:

```vb
For Each cmbx In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)().ToArray()
    cmbx.Dispose()
Next
```

The `OfType` does the filtering first and then the `ToArray` creates an array that you can loop over, so you're not enumerating and modifying a collection at the same time. There's no point removing and disposing the controls because disposing will implicitly remove them.

Comment: Nice tip. I'm just off to edit all my backwards For..Next loops

Comment: @DavidWilson, a backwards `For...Next` is more efficient, because it only loops once. The code provided here enumerates the original collection first to get the array, then enumerates the array. Unless you're dealing with a very large collection though, the difference will be negligible and, in my opinion, this code is more succinct.

Comment: Sorry - just read my prev comment - there was no negative connotation intended - I do think its a good tip.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se usa Panel:

```
for each ctrl in me.controls
    if typeof ctrl is system.windows.forms.TextBox then
        ctrl.text = ""
    elseif typeof ctrl is system.windows.forms.panel then
        for each pctrl in ctrl.controls
            if typeof pctrl is system.windows.forms.textbox then
                pctrl.text = ""
             end if
        next
     end if
next
```

xt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).